# German decompounding - enforce searching for all split parts of the word

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find out how a search can be implemented well for the German language. My problem is that German allows to easily create compound words. To allow to search for them I have created a compound dictionary and added to an analyser. When I use the analyser to search for "Webentwickler" (web developer):

```
{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "dictionary_decompounder",
      "word_list": ["web"]
    }
  ],
  "text": "webentwickler"
}
```

it returns the tokens `["webentwickler", "web"]`.

Now when I am searching for job ads with **"webentwickler"** I have the problem that either I enforce the search to use all tokens and therefore do not find **"web entwickler"** jobs (**"webentwickler"** is not in the job posting) or I do not enfore to search all tokens and also get a lot job adds with only the word **"web"** in it. Therefore I would need an analyser solution that returns the tokens `["web", "entwickler"]` - I only want to split the word and add it split to the tokens.

How can I implement a search that uses a compound word list but allow to enforce that all compound split tokens must occur in the result?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?